# Changing notification sound of cordova-plugin-dialogs

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

In earlier versions of `cordova-plugin-dialogs` it was possible to make your custom notification sound as noticed in [earlier documentations](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.5.0/phonegap/notification/notification.beep.html) of the official plugin of cordova [`cordova-plugin-dialogs`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/#page-toc-source).

However, [in currect version](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/#page-toc-source), I couldn't find any way to change the notification sound of `beep` function, either in settings of iOS or by adding a custom ´wav´ file in `www` folder.

Any idea how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier documentation only allowed a custom sound for Android as it had no default beep sound. There was no override for iOS. I guess since then, Android got its default sound. You couldn't change it for iOS and now you can't for Android too.

Comment: So, currently there is no way to change the sound?

Comment: That's right...